# Transform curl to js(ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl

I want to create an API to send a photo or video to https://partner.path.com/1/moment/photo(recorded as A)

It can be done successfully by curl as the following:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>' 
-F "image=@F:photo.jpg" 
-F 'data={"caption": "I like cheese!"}' 
A
```

However,it is failed(400 BAD_REQUEST) when sending the request by Ajax as the following:

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST",  
url : "A",
async : false,
data : "{"image":"@F:photo.jpg", "caption":"I like the picture", "private":true}",
dataType : 'json',
contentType : "application/json",
crossDomain : true,
beforeSend : function(xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 5f323a1c21a89cde270ffe78b3835d8a4bdd67c0");
},
success : function(res, textStatus) {
console.log(res);               
}
});
```

I think the problem maybe exist on the parameters(particularly the data parameter) when making ajax call.
What is the correct format of the data parameter?

Comment: check syntax for $.ajax() [link](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) .........data parameters syntax maybe wrong

Comment: Change the quotes... like `data : '{"image":"@F:photo.jpg", "caption":"I like the picture", "private":true}',` don't use both double quotes.